# Elasticsearch No Living connections

Tags: elasticsearch, npm

I am using elasticsearch node module(https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) with version 14.2.2. But sometimes when I tried to add data into the index using a module method it is giving me the following error:

> "No Living connections"

May I know the all possible reasons for the reason?